# How to configure Sharepoint site for intranet?

Tags: sharepoint, iis, intranet

I am basically a windows developer and very new to Sharepoint. I have Designed a small site in sharepoint on my virtual PC environment.

I want to access it from out side of VPC environment and also from other local LAN machines [like intranet].

How do i configure (IIS/Sharepoint Adm) to make my site as an intranet site?
I googled it, but not able to get desired information.  I don't have much knowledge in ISS setting also, kindly provide any help in layman style.

Comment: This would be better asked on http://serverfault.com also with the tag `virtualpc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Virtual PC to use [**Virtual Networking**](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/cm/virtualization-vpc-vserv-page1.html):

> In this case a virtual machine acts as
>   an independent computer in a network
>   with the host computer. If there is a
>   DHCP server in the network (Dynamic
>   Host Configuration Protocol) to assign
>   IP addresses, a virtual machine will
>   get it and will work as an independent
>   system in the network (otherwise, you
>   will have to specify an external IP
>   manually)

This is actually the default option in Virtual PC. You should be able to access the VM on the network as you would your own machine. Of course this means the VM's network settings must be valid for your network.

You shouldn't have to reconfigure anything is IIS/Sharepoint Adm to get this to work.